# What Linux kernel interfaces does the System76 Gnome Power Management extension use to set CPU governor policies?

Tags: power-management, cpufreq

Just for a reference, I am speaking about the following System 76 Power Management Gnome extension available on System 76 laptop.

[image]

No matter whether I set the power management to "High Performance", "Balanced" or "Battery Life" none of the following Linux CPU freq management control points are affected:

- /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct
- /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
- /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
- /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/energy_performance_preference

However, when power management is set to "Battery Life" the CPU frequency never goes above 2,100 MHz, while when one of the other two modes is selected, then the CPU frequency can go as high as 4,1000 MHz.